# Issues while ssh to beanstalk environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, ssh, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am running into a weird issue and it's driving me nuts. My app is hosted on ElasticBeanstalk and since yesterday, I was not able to `ssh` into my environment.

Everytime, I try `eb ssh {ENVIRONMENT_NAME}` or `eb ssh` I get: `ebcli.lib.aws : Botocore Error`

However, I am still able to deploy but this issues appears when I try to `ssh` / `eb status --verbose`

Detailed output below:

```
$ eb ssh
(ERROR) ebcli.lib.aws : Botocore Error
ERROR: EndpointConnectionError - Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://ec2.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/"
```

My `~/.aws/config` file:

```
[profile eb-cli]
aws_access_key_id = ACCESS_KEY_ID_HERE
aws_secret_access_key = SECRET_KEY_GOES_HERE
```

Below is the output when I tried to debug:

```
$ eb ssh --debug
2018-04-14 13:23:51,414 (DEBUG) cement.core.foundation : laying cement for the 'eb' application
2018-04-14 13:23:51,414 (DEBUG) cement.core.hook : defining hook 'pre_setup'
2018-04-14 13:23:51,414 (DEBUG) cement.core.hook : defining hook 'post_setup'
2018-04-14 13:23:51,414 (DEBUG) cement.core.hook : defining hook 'pre_run'
2018-04-14 13:23:51,414 (DEBUG) cement.core.hook : defining hook 'post_run'
2018-04-14 13:23:51,415 (DEBUG) cement.core.hook : defining hook 'pre_argument_parsing'
2018-04-14 13:23:51,415 (DEBUG) cement.core.hook : defining hook 'post_argument_parsing'
2018-04-14 13:23:51,415 (DEBUG) cement.core.hook : defining hook 'pre_close'
2018-04-14 13:23:51,415 (DEBUG) cement.core.hook : defining hook 'post_close'
2018-04-14 13:23:51,415 (DEBUG) cement.core.hook : defining hook 'signal'
2018-04-14 13:23:51,415 (DEBUG) cement.core.hook : defining hook 'pre_render'
2018-04-14 13:23:51,415 (DEBUG) cement.core.hook : defining hook 'post_render'
2018-04-14 13:23:51,416 (DEBUG) cement.core.hook : registering hook 'add_handler_override_options' from cement.core.foundation into hooks['post_setup']
2018-04-14 13:23:51,416 (DEBUG) cement.core.hook : registering hook 'handler_override' from cement.core.foundation into hooks['post_argument_parsing']
2018-04-14 13:23:51,416 (DEBUG) cement.core.handler : defining handler type 'extension' (IExtension)
2018-04-14 13:23:51,416 (DEBUG) cement.core.handler : defining handler type 'log' (ILog)
2018-04-14 13:23:51,416 (DEBUG) cement.core.handler : defining handler type 'config' (IConfig)
2018-04-14 13:23:51,416 (DEBUG) cement.core.handler : defining handler type 'mail' (IMail)
2018-04-14 13:23:51,416 (DEBUG) cement.core.handler : defining handler type 'plugin' (IPlugin)
2018-04-14 13:23:51,417 (DEBUG) cement.core.handler : defining handler type 'output' (IOutput)
2018-04-14 13:23:51,417 (DEBUG) cement.core.handler : defining handler type 'argument' (IArgument)
2018-04-14 13:23:51,417 (DEBUG) cement.core.handler : defining handler type 'controller' (IController)
2018-04-14 13:23:51,417 (DEBUG) cement.core.handler : defining handler type 'cache' (ICache)
2018-04-14 13:23:51,418 (DEBUG) cement.core.handler : registering handler '<class 'cement.core.extension.CementExtensionHandler'>' into handlers['extension']['cement']
2018-04-14 13:23:51,418 (DEBUG) ebcli.core.fileoperations : Project root found at: PATH_TO_PROJECT
2018-04-14 13:23:51,431 (DEBUG) ebcli.core.fileoperations : Project root found at: PATH_TO_PROJECT
2018-04-14 13:23:51,437 (DEBUG) ebcli.core.fileoperations : Project root found at: PATH_TO_PROJECT
2018-04-14 13:23:51,460 (DEBUG) cement.ext.ext_plugin : plugin config dir /etc/eb/plugins.d does not exist.
2018-04-14 13:23:51,460 (DEBUG) cement.ext.ext_plugin : plugin config dir /Users/r/.eb/plugins.d does not exist.
2018-04-14 13:23:51,471 (DEBUG) ebcli.core.hooks : -- EBCLI Version: 3.12.4
2018-04-14 13:23:51,471 (DEBUG) ebcli.core.hooks : -- Python Version: 2.7.10 (default, Oct  6 2017, 22:29:07) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.31)]
2018-04-14 13:23:51,471 (DEBUG) ebcli.core.fileoperations : Project root found at: PATH_TO_PROJECT
2018-04-14 13:23:51,477 (DEBUG) ebcli.objects.sourcecontrol : Getting current branch name by performing `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`
2018-04-14 13:23:51,504 (DEBUG) ebcli.objects.sourcecontrol : branch-name
2018-04-14 13:23:51,505 (DEBUG) ebcli.core.fileoperations : Project root found at: PATH_TO_PROJECT
2018-04-14 13:23:51,512 (DEBUG) ebcli.core.fileoperations : Project root found at: PATH_TO_PROJECT
2018-04-14 13:23:51,517 (DEBUG) ebcli.core.fileoperations : Project root found at: PATH_TO_PROJECT
2018-04-14 13:23:51,522 (DEBUG) ebcli.objects.sourcecontrol : Getting current branch name by performing `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`
2018-04-14 13:23:51,530 (DEBUG) ebcli.objects.sourcecontrol : branch-name
2018-04-14 13:23:51,531 (DEBUG) ebcli.core.fileoperations : Project root found at: PATH_TO_PROJECT
2018-04-14 13:23:51,536 (DEBUG) ebcli.core.fileoperations : Project root found at: PATH_TO_PROJECT
2018-04-14 13:23:51,542 (DEBUG) ebcli.core.fileoperations : Project root found at: PATH_TO_PROJECT
2018-04-14 13:23:51,548 (DEBUG) ebcli.core.fileoperations : Project root found at: PATH_TO_PROJECT
2018-04-14 13:23:51,553 (DEBUG) ebcli.objects.sourcecontrol : Getting current branch name by performing `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`
2018-04-14 13:23:51,562 (DEBUG) ebcli f.objects.sourcecontrol : branch-name
2018-04-14 13:23:51,563 (DEBUG) ebcli.core.fileoperations : Project root found at: PATH_TO_PROJECT
2018-04-14 13:23:51,569 (DEBUG) ebcli.core.fileoperations : Project root found at: PATH_TO_PROJECT
2018-04-14 13:23:51,574 (DEBUG) ebcli.lib.elasticbeanstalk : Inside get_environment_resources api wrapper
2018-04-14 13:23:51,574 (DEBUG) ebcli.lib.aws : Creating new Botocore Session
2018-04-14 13:23:51,574 (DEBUG) ebcli.lib.aws : Botocore version: 1.8.41
2018-04-14 13:23:51,576 (DEBUG) ebcli.lib.aws : Creating new Botocore Client for elasticbeanstalk
2018-04-14 13:23:51,650 (DEBUG) ebcli.lib.aws : Successfully created session for elasticbeanstalk
2018-04-14 13:23:51,650 (DEBUG) ebcli.lib.aws : Making api call: (elasticbeanstalk, describe_environment_resources) to region: us-east-1 with args:{'EnvironmentName': 'ENV-NAME'}
2018-04-14 13:23:56,873 (DEBUG) ebcli.lib.aws : API call finished, status = 200
2018-04-14 13:23:56,875 (DEBUG) ebcli.lib.aws : Creating new Botocore Client for ec2
2018-04-14 13:24:01,238 (DEBUG) ebcli.lib.aws : Successfully created session for ec2
2018-04-14 13:24:01,238 (DEBUG) ebcli.lib.aws : Making api call: (ec2, describe_instances) to region: us-east-1 with args:{'InstanceIds': ['i-0397b815f11d2e073']}
2018-04-14 13:24:08,314 (ERROR) ebcli.lib.aws : Botocore Error
2018-04-14 13:24:08,331 (INFO) eb : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-elasticbeanstalk/3.12.4/libexec/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ebcli/core/ebrun.py", line 41, in run_app
app.run()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-elasticbeanstalk/3.12.4/libexec/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cement/core/foundation.py", line 797, in run
return_val = self.controller._dispatch()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-elasticbeanstalk/3.12.4/libexec/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cement/core/controller.py", line 472, in _dispatch
return func()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-elasticbeanstalk/3.12.4/libexec/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cement/core/controller.py", line 478, in _dispatch
return func()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-elasticbeanstalk/3.12.4/libexec/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ebcli/core/abstractcontroller.py", line 60, in default
self.do_command()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-elasticbeanstalk/3.12.4/libexec/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ebcli/controllers/ssh.py", line 58, in do_command
command=cmd)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-elasticbeanstalk/3.12.4/libexec/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ebcli/operations/sshops.py", line 58, in prepare_for_ssh
ssh_into_instance(instance, keep_open=keep_open, force_open=force, custom_ssh=custom_ssh, command=command)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-elasticbeanstalk/3.12.4/libexec/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ebcli/operations/sshops.py", line 82, in ssh_into_instance
instance = ec2.describe_instance(instance_id)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-elasticbeanstalk/3.12.4/libexec/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ebcli/lib/ec2.py", line 58, in describe_instance
result = describe_instances([instance_id])
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-elasticbeanstalk/3.12.4/libexec/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ebcli/lib/ec2.py", line 48, in describe_instances
InstanceIds=instance_ids)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-elasticbeanstalk/3.12.4/libexec/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ebcli/lib/ec2.py", line 25, in _make_api_call
return aws.make_api_call('ec2', operation_name, **operation_options)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-elasticbeanstalk/3.12.4/libexec/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ebcli/lib/aws.py", line 212, in make_api_call
response_data = operation(**operation_options)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-elasticbeanstalk/3.12.4/libexec/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 324, in _api_call
return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-elasticbeanstalk/3.12.4/libexec/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 609, in _make_api_call
operation_model, request_dict)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-elasticbeanstalk/3.12.4/libexec/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 143, in make_request
return self._send_request(request_dict, operation_model)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-elasticbeanstalk/3.12.4/libexec/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 172, in _send_request
success_response, exception):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-elasticbeanstalk/3.12.4/libexec/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 265, in _needs_retry
caught_exception=caught_exception, request_dict=request_dict)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-elasticbeanstalk/3.12.4/libexec/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 227, in emit
return self._emit(event_name, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-elasticbeanstalk/3.12.4/libexec/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 210, in _emit
response = handler(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-elasticbeanstalk/3.12.4/libexec/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 183, in __call__
if self._checker(attempts, response, caught_exception):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-elasticbeanstalk/3.12.4/libexec/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 251, in __call__
caught_exception)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-elasticbeanstalk/3.12.4/libexec/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 277, in _should_retry
return self._checker(attempt_number, response, caught_exception)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-elasticbeanstalk/3.12.4/libexec/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 317, in __call__
caught_exception)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-elasticbeanstalk/3.12.4/libexec/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 223, in __call__
attempt_number, caught_exception)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-elasticbeanstalk/3.12.4/libexec/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 359, in _check_caught_exception
raise caught_exception
EndpointConnectionError: Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://ec2.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/"

2018-04-14 13:24:08,332 (INFO) eb : EndpointConnectionError - Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://ec2.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/"
```

Any help on this would be highly appreciated!

Comment: do you mean until yesterday `eb ssh` was working okay?

Comment: yes. Strange this is, when I change the n/w settings (i.e. connect to a different network), `eb ssh` starts working

Comment: I suspect this could be a temporary glitch with my n/w settings